# Music volume turning off when headphones moved around

Tags: music-player, headphone-jack

I have an LG Lucid with Android 2.3.6 and I have a big issue with my music. I'm not sure if this is an Android setting or a LG one, but I'm hoping to find a way for this to stop happening.

I use my phone a lot to listen to music, and one of my biggest issues is if the headphone jack gets moved even the slightest, the music automatically pauses and reduces volume. I usually have my phone in my pocket and listening to music while working out, jogging or doing housework. This feature has basically made the music playback feature of my phone useless, as I can not do any of these things without the music constantly pausing and lowering in volume.

This happens in my car as well, with my wireless FM transmitter: even the slightest bump or movement of my phone on the car seat and music stops.

Please, tell me there is a way to fix this: it would be greatly appreciated. Also, like I said before, I'm not sure if this is an LG or Android thing, so if anyone can verify that I would also appreciate it.

Comment: Yes its an android feature check out the settings of your default music app and their should be an option about "Start/pause the music when headphones connect". It may be differ on your LG as its on my Sony phone. Just unmarked it and here you go on.

Comment: Very strange I had that option in GB but not in ICS as I figured it out just now after suggesting you. :P

Comment: Give a try to [Headset Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker&referrer=utm_source%3Dappbrain%26utm_medium%3Dappbrain_web%26utm_campaign%3Dappbrain_web).

Comment: Do your headphones have a start/stop button? Could be related to this issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54985/283707

Comment: Had an issue similar, but only at full volume. Try turning it down a bit and see if it still pauses out

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a bad connector problem.

Try cleaning the headphone plug using a rough-ish cloth to clean up the (probably unseen) oxidation layer.

Spray the plug using a contact cleaner, then while it's not yet dried, plug it into the jack and do some left-and-right rotation. Unplug, and let the plug dry. Then replug, and do the rotations again.

If the above does not fix your problem, there's possibility that the solder contact between the jack and the phone's mainboard has cracked; you need to bring your phone to the service center (or someone skillful enough to perform cellphone repairs).

Comment: That's kind of depressing haha, was hoping there would be a quick and cheap fix. I'll def try that though, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best solution that is if you don't want to factory reset your phone. I tried putting a layer of tape over the earphone hijack and voila the issue was gone. Needless to say that it is definitely not an app or software issue but with the hijack itself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds rough but try romving bits of the Cotten off a q-tip and squeeze some of it in there the reason mine was malfunctioning was because there was dust in there so all you had to do was clean it up. And no using this method won't jack up your sound because I've been doing this for a while now and my sound works perfectly. (Try this at your own risk, NOT SAYING IT WON'T WORK!! But...)